# Why is Google App Script not receiving my file uploads with doPost() when using form-data in Postman?

Tags: http, google-apps-script

I'm having trouble receiving file uploads in Google App Script with `doPost()`.

Using Postman, I send a POST request to the deployed Google App Script Web App URL. The body of the request is set to form-data and includes two files (file1: print.pdf, file2: data.csv).

In Google App Script, I log the request with:

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

This logs the following:
`{"contentLength":116382,"parameter":{},"parameters":{},"queryString":"","contextPath":""}`

Given the parameter(s) objects are empty, does this mean the Web App cannot receive files through form-data?

**Note:** The reason I am sending files with form-data is because I am building this script to process POST requests from a third-party application which sends mutliple files using form-data (I can't change this).